# How Do I override property set in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

how do I override a simple property in cocos2dx?

I used to do this working with cocos2d and objective-c:

.h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)float someProperty;
```

.m file:

```
-(void)setSomeProperty:(float)someProperty
{
    //some custom code
    self.someProperty = someProperty;
}
```

I would like to do the same in cocos2dx, thanks for any tips

Comment: You implement the setter/getter methods. C++ has no concept of properties, so to access a member variable the programmer implements two methods getXXXX and setXXXX where get returns the value and set assigns it. The set/get naming is just by convention, you could also name them differently ie haveXXXX, assignXXXX

Comment: not sure if I got the picture

Comment: Say, you want to override the position setter/getter. Open CCNode source files, copy & paste their implementation to your CCNode subclass. You may need to add an "override" keyword or something, I'm not really fluent in C++ anymore. If you could post an attempt you made feel free to ask a new question regarding specific implementation problems.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I looked into the classes, it was not quite clear to me, I am new in c++. I decided to create a method that would simulate the setter.